# how to add a conditional compilation constant to VB.NET WEB APP

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

In a VB.NET Windows app, I can add a global symbol to Projects > Compile > Advanced > Custom constants

How do I do this for a Web app?   Where is Custom constants defined?
The project > Properties is very limited compared to a VB Windows app.
Solution to this is to use web app and not web site.

But I still need a global conditional compilation constant, preferably defined in the Projects > Compile > Advanced > "Custom constants" text box.
If I used #Const, it is only accessible in the same file.